# How can I make a view to show all own comments?

Tags: views, nodes

I'm trying to show all comments the logged user did on a forum from the module advanced forum. 
I've tried using views, adding a relationship with content:autor and filtering by user:current. But didn't work. Also I've tried contextual filter with the parameter comment :author id.
Anyone can help?

I'm using D7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to create a view.

- Login as admin
- Go to admin/structure/views/import
- Copy paste below code in "Paste view code here"

**$Below code**

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user_forum_comments';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'comment';
$view->human_name = 'User Forum Comments';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE;

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'User Forum Comments';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'comment';
/* Relationship: Comment: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Comment: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['id'] = 'subject';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['field'] = 'subject';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['subject']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Comment: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Comment: Author uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Comment: Approved */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['id'] = 'status_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_node']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'forum' => 'forum',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user-forum-comments';
```

- Click on Import
- Go to user-forum-comments to see results
- Go to admin/structure/views/view/user_forum_comments/edit to see how view is constructed.

Hope it answers :-)

Comment: Cannot able to get code formatting on copy pasted code.... Any help ?

Comment: Really helpful ^^ thx!!!